# UICollectionViewCell layout issues iOS9

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios9, xcode7

Since my move to the new iOS9 and Xcode 7 I have stumbled upon an issue with one of the `UICollectionView` in my app.

Apparently, the `UICollectionView` doesn't seem to update the `UICollectionViewCell` layout and constraints properly, only until it is reused.

Pictures speak better than words -- this is how it looks like when the `UIViewController` is first seen:
[image]

However this isn't the correct layout, and easily enough when I swipe the `UICollectionView` horizontally to the left, I get the right layout of the newly appeared cells:
[image]

When I swipe back, the old cells that weren't correct, are now reused and look good.

Now, as it was prior to upgrading to iOS9 and Xcode 7, my wanted effect is that the cells have the correct layout even when first appearing.

For your convenience, here are more details on how the `UICollectionView` is set up and it's constraints in the XIB:
[image]

In the code, it is pretty standard:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : MatchmakersCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MatchmakersCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    cell.bottomName.text = "StackOverflow"

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.matchmakers.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

And every time I updated the datasource (self.matchmakers), I called `self.collectionView.reloadData()`

One last thing I had noticed which was very strange, when debugging with Xcode the debug view hierarchy, the `UICollectionViewCell` never presented the subviews properly and just gave me a default `UIView` in their stead:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

To solve this problem:

1. Creat your custom UICollectionViewCell using **Nib(.xib)** files.
2. In your custom UICollectionViewCell ,**override didMoveToSuperView()** method to add this

   **self.setNeedLayout()**

   **self.layoutIfNeeded()**

3.In your UIViewController **viewDidLoad()** method

**self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "yourNibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")**

--------update 20150923

just need step 2, override didMoveToSuperView method to add

**self.setNeedLayout()**

**self.layoutIfNeeded()**

in your custom UICollectionViewCell class.

Thanks @macayer

Comment: Calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` methods in `- (void)didMoveToSuperview` inside the custom item class did the trick for me on iOS 9.0 public release. I'm wondering how is this in efficiency terms though... The `viewDidLoad` part and also the separate `Nib` file weren't necessary.

Comment: Step 1 and 3 aren't necessary. Step 2 is just what you need.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have to create my own XIB for my cell, as long as I have my custom cell and have it linked into my storyboard, I just added those line in (MyCustomCollectionViewCell.m):

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same bug in iOS9 too. Perhaps you've found that it's all ok after you reloaded the collection view. So my solution: set a timer for iOS9 to reload the cells.

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
   self.refreshTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("refreshDataTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

And reload them :

```
func refreshDataTimer(){

    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

}
```

Even though this solution is little stupid but it works in few lines.

or you can reload each cell :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     .... 


    self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
    return cell
}
```

But it's inefficient.

Comment: Why this solution is working as reloadItemsAtIndexPaths method will call cellForRowAtcellForRowAt and then again it will execute method  reloadItemsAtIndexPaths  so I want a reason why this solution works ??

Comment: Bit nasty...  At best there is an unneeded delay for UI to appear and at worst the Timer assumes that the view finished loading (may still happen).

Answer (score 1):

I had same bug in iOS9. I would like center x and center y image to UICollectionView Cell. It doesnt work, but now I added in storyboard `Align Top` and `Align Leading`, then I added outlets `NSLayoutConstraint` and in

`(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. I am changing `NSLayoutConstraint` depending on the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty positive this is an iOS9 bug. Instead of setting up the `UICollectionViewCell` UI and constraints in the `UICollectionView` in the Storyboard, I created it its own XIB. Then added to the `UIViewController`:

```
self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MatchmakersCollectionViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
```

Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had one part of the issue the OP described...

> One last thing I had noticed which was very strange, when debugging
>   with Xcode the debug view hierarchy, the UICollectionViewCell never
>   presented the subviews properly and just gave me a default UIView in
>   their stead

I spent ages bashing my head against a wall trying to work out what was up, none of the suggested answers made a difference.  In the end I ended up deleting all the constraints in my cells XIB and re-adding them and it fixed the problem.  I guess the constraints must've corrupted at some point.

Hope it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case disabling size classes in .xib file did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the appropriate Swift 2.0 code needed to solve this issue in Xcode 7.  Note that the correct code is 'setNeedsLayout' and not 'SetNeedLayout' as stated above.  Make sure to call it in the UICollectionViewCell file.

```
 override func didMoveToSuperview() {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```